# In windows DirectShow then what is in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, directshow

previously in windows I used DirectShow, for camera applications, but now I shifted to
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and here I want to develop application for webcam streaming, so is there any thing that is equivalent to DirectShow in linux.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is something like DirectShow on linux: gstreamer. But if you only want to capture something Video4Linux might be enough.

Comment: I want to implement with gtk, and I need to Read/write access to standard device setings will gstreamer is fine, or recently I found **libuvvc**, will it be helpful.